# Explanation on the difference between Last Epoch Validation Results vs Evaluation on Validation Set

Tags: machine-learning

I have trained a machine learning model and have a question.

As a random trial, I noticed that there is a huge difference between the

1. Last EPOCH validation results against
2. Evaluation results against the Validation Set

Shouldn't they be the same or at least similar? Am aware that you don't evaluate on the validation set but just like to find out the reason behind this.

Appreciate if anyone can enlighten me.
Thank you.

Comment: there should not be any different between last epoch validation results and evaluation results. if there are then you might have changed the dataset some how.

Comment: look for errors